# How to rebase root project when submodules have been rebased

Tags: git, git-submodules, rebase

I have a project that uses many submodules. I have rebase all submodules to squash and clean commits, and also to implement semantic release.

I wanted to rebase and squash commits also on the root project that contains the submodules, but I get many errors like:

```
CONFLICT (submodule): Merge conflict in <submodule>
error: could not apply fe0f57c... <message>
```

This is I guess because the commit references have changed during the rebase of the submodules, so the root project cannot find them anymore.

What is the strategy in this case to solve the problem?

Comment: Please, edit you post and provide us the list of conflicts.

Comment: `I guess because the commit references have changed during the rebase ... so the root project cannot find them anymore` Not finding commits is not the problem here. While references change during a rebase, the old thing that was referenced does **not** immediately disappear. Maybe the commit is referenced by some other branch of tag for instance, and if really nothing references a commit it will only be garbage collected some time later in the future (after 1 month IIRC).

Comment: What you have here seems to be a normal, plain merge conflict. For submodules you need to check out the commit you want to use (`cd mysubmod; git checkout $THE_COMMIT_I_WANT_TO_USE; cd ..`) and then update the commit reference for the submodule (`git add mysubmod`).

Comment: Is it possible to remove all the submodules and then start from scratch? I think the cleanest solution would be to fix the `main`/`master` branches of all submodules, then `git submodule init` and start over.

Comment: @Eljas Hyyrynen Yes that could be a solution but we will lose 4 months of commit history in the main branch, that contains submodules but also scripts, migrations and configurations.

Comment: @hlovdal I do not have tags and I have been working on my dev branch only, still have to merge on main and anyway I do not understand how that could be a problem. I will check tomorrow and post the whole error, could be a merge conflict but I do not understand why it is appearing and how to actually solve it without breaking the git repo.

Comment: Please explain me why you would lose anything if all your submodules are ever only on `main` branch? You would just "fix" the merge conflicts by accepting whatever the submodules have. The repository using the submodules shouldn't have any edits on those. Otherwise you'll end up with a mess.

Comment: @Eljas Hyyrynen If I delete the whole git history and restart from scratch then I will lose the git history on the root branch. If you meant just to delete the submodules and adding them again, how is this going solve the problem? The conflict happens during the squash of older commits. Even if I delete submodules and add them again, there will still be the same problem when I will try to squash the root commits.

Comment: That is not what I meant.

If you meant you're altering the history of the submodules: then just solve the conflict on the parent repository by checking out / reseting to the submodule after the history has been altered.

If you meant you're changing the history on the parent repository: then just make sure the submodules point to the right commit.

`I guess because the commit references have changed during the rebase of the submodules`  then you should do `git submodule update` if you want to go to the latest commit in the submodules. If not, just checkout manually.